# Spring Web Security Incorrect Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to enable basic http authentication for the `actuator` endpoints while keeping the jwt authentication for the `api` endpoints. I tried the following configuration for this:

```java
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .anonymous()
        .disable()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .antMatcher("/service/actuator/**")
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/service/api/**")
        .authenticated()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint);

    http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
```

However, it appears that I can use the JWT token and basic auth as well for the `actuator` endpoints while no authentication also works for all the `api` endpoints.
Did I mess up the order? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following worked for me

```java
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .anonymous()
        .disable()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/service/actuator/**")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/service/api/**")
        .authenticated()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint);

    http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
```